# Passing date from jsp to controller in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a form :

```
<form method="post" action="/addExpense">
<input type="text" name="description" required>
<input type="number" name="amount" required>
<input type="date" name="created" required>
<input type="date" name="updated" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and in my controller I have a method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addExpense", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String addExpense(@ModelAttribute("expenseDetailDTO") ExpenseDetailDTO expenseDetailDTO) {
    expenseService.addExpense(expenseDetailDTO);
    return "true";
}
```

ExpenseDetailDTO contents :

```
public class ExpenseDetailDTO {
String description;
Long amount;
Date created;
Date updated;
...
}
```

when I submit the form in throws 400 Bad Request. When checking the form data in the chrome dev tools it shows :

```
description:description
amount:500
created:2016-01-01
updated:2016-01-01
```

I think Spring is not able to convert the Date from form in java.util.Date.

How can I pass date to controller?

EDIT :

Added the annotation for DateTimeFormat :

```
public class ExpenseDetailDTO {
String description;
Long amount;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Date created;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Date updated;
....
}
```

Still giving 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following annotations

`@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date created
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date updated`

on your ExpenseDetailDTO class date properties

Answer (score 0):

You should format date using Spring DateTimeAnnotation

Answer (score 0):

Use initbinder method in controller to bind date values from jsp.

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
        dateFormat, false));
}
```